# SQLite.Net Extensions issue with InsertOrReplaceWithChildren

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am using SQLite-Net PCL together with SQLite-Net extensions for the development of an application using Xamarin.

I have two classes `A` and `B` defined as follows:

```
public class A
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Unique]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<B> Sons
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public A(string name, List<B> sons)
    {
        Name = name;
        Sons = sons;
    }

}

public class B
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Unique]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastModified
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(A))]
    public int FatherId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ManyToOne]
    public A Father
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public B()
    {
    }

    public B(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

I am trying to use insert or replace in the following way:

```
        var sons1 = new List<B>
        {
            new B("uno"),
        };

        var a1 = new A("padre", sons1);

        var sons2 = new List<B>
        {
            new B("uno2"),
        };

        var a2 = new A("padre", sons2);

        using (var conn = DatabaseStore.GetConnection())
        {
            conn.DeleteAll<A>();
            conn.DeleteAll<B>();
        }

        using (var conn = DatabaseStore.GetConnection())
        {
            conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(a1, true);
            conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(a2, true);
        }
```

The problem is that the second `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren` is throwing a `Constraint` exception, that is not thrown if we remove the unique constraint on `A.Name`. Isn't   `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren` supposed to replace the object if a unique constraint is violated?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Probably here: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/fe7c6539bf56f652aae06d0af26b54cff2ffcfd3/SQLiteNetExtensions/Extensions/WriteOperations.cs?at=master#cl-272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the commits for that line, now I remember: it seems that the `AutoIncrement` primary key only works for `Insert` statements and not for `InsertOrReplace`. As consequence if you call `InsertOrReplace` with an `AutoIncrement` primary key set to 0, it will always overwrite the same value in the database with ID 0 instead of correctly adding new values.

This issue is easy to check by executing this test:

```
var a = new List<A> {
    new A("a1", null),
    new A("a2", null),
    new A("a3", null),
    new A("a4", null),
    new A("a5", null),
    new A("a6", null)
};

foreach (var element in a) {
    conn.InsertOrReplace(element);
}

// Will fail expecting 6 elements but returning only 1
Assert.AreEqual(a.Count, conn.Table<A>().ToList().Count);
```

To solve it you have to give up either the `AutoIncrement` primary key or the `Unique` constraint check for the `InsertOrReplace` statement to work.

These are drop-in replacement classes that should work as expected giving up the `AutoIncrement` primary keys:

```
public class A
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<B> Sons { get; set; }

    public A() {}
    public A(string name, List<B> sons)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
        Sons = sons;
    }
}

public class B
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastModified { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(A))]
    public Guid FatherId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public A Father { get; set; }

    public B() {}

    public B(string name)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I'm working on a data model that is more complicated than this one, so every time I am inserting I'm checking if the object is already there. To be honest, I had another more strange issue, that unfortunately I didn't manage to reproduce with a smaller example, but I've found a workaround also for that.

Comment: Besides, I think that a source of confusion is also given by the fact that your example will work with `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren` and it will correctly assign the IDs